# mongodb wont read config file using upstart

Tags: mongodb, debian

The problem started where mongo wouldn't start because of low disk space. So I enabled the small files directive in the config file. Now it starts if I run:

```
/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

and it starts

```
service mongod start
```

and it fails from the same error about disk space, leading me to believe that it's just not reading the config file.

i added an echo statement to the upstart script and i see this:

```
Starting database: mongodstart-stop-daemon --background --start --quiet --pidfile /var/run/mongod.pid --make-pidfile --chuid mongodb --exec  /usr/bin/mongod  -- --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

Config file: https://gist.github.com/macdabby/3ee375be72ab3a3f11a7

Upstart script: https://gist.github.com/macdabby/192891a1ae690d4ec57c

Debian wheezy and mongodb 3.0.1

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though it was reading the config file but reading it in a different way that it was ignoring a certain directive. I tried setting smallfiles to true which worked when starting manually. But in service mode I got it to work by disabling journaling. Not sure if this is a bug.